How to Accurately calculate a solana Stake pools APY?
I was Trying to Find my stake-pool apy,with this equation
const poolPk = new PublicKey("6d9Fg5qPMfcezk5KzyLv7erXo8zrxvNWKQGAcBLf3NQo")

const preValuePerToken = 1408010046/1407999406;
console.log(preValuePerToken)
const pool = await getStakePoolAccount(connection, poolPk);

// console.log(postPool)

// const postValuePerToken = pool.account.data.totalLamports / pool.account.data.poolTokenSupply;
const postValuePerToken = 1408774149/1408029955

console.log(postValuePerToken)


const percentChange = postValuePerToken/preValuePerToken;


const epochsPerYear = 161;
const apy = (Math.pow(percentChange, epochsPerYear) - 1) * 100;
console.log('APY:', apy.toFixed(2) + '%'); 

console.log(percentChange)

it gives 13% apy for some reason for epoch 649 and If i try to calculate apy of epoch 650 even to it is 60% completed , I get the apy of 6.25% Which result in a bigger apy at the end.
There is no new deposit in the pool still i get This High apy for some reason

That's very strange, rewards are only paid out at the epoch boundary, so even if the epoch is 60% completed you shouldn't have any change. Be sure that you're doing these calculations every epoch, and not every other epoch

It seens like the rewards are paid after a while of the epoch start and not at the boundary. And the apy is still messed up.
